# Can I move my asp.net mvc app into microsoft cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud

without making a lot of changes. Did anyone try it? Are there any known patterns to work with for cloud computing using Azure platform.

Answer (score 1):

First part of the question, the answer is yes. You can deploy MVC on Windows Azure.

For considerations on designing and developing apps for Windows Azure see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728592.aspx). In the next couple days we will publish a second sample app that is based on MVC 2.0. See [here](http://wag.codeplex.com).